AWS RDS - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'ec2-ip' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
My Laravel(hosted on EC2) app database(Mysql) is hosted in AWS RDS it was working fine but now it gives the error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172...***' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server, for every API call. I can't connect db to run any SQL query (like SHOW GRANTS) and try to change the security inbound. Some suggest to run run this
mysql -h rdsendpoint -u admin -p 
but I am unable to connect.
Security group of EC2 that is used in RDS is
enter image description here

If ec2's ip is changed, you should check:

MYSQL user table to update user's ip.
Security group for RDS Mysql.

And if security group for ec2 is changed maybe checking it outbound rule will help. (Add 0.0.0.0/0 ALL)
You can check connection using the way you are doing:
mysql -h rdsendpoint -u admin -p

